# Copy the rsa keys from one machine to another

Tags: ssh, rsa

Someone asked me to provide my public id_rsa key to make be able to connect to their server via ssh. I did so and it's working fine. I want to do that from my another laptop as well without having to bother them. If I just copy a public and a private keys from my first laptop to the second one, will it allow me to connect to the server? Note I already have a private and public rsa keys on my **second** laptop that are, of course, different from the ones from the first laptop.

What's the best way to do so - copy the keys?

Comment: Best practice is to have one keypair per device you're connecting from. So generate a new keypair on the 2nd laptop and send that public key to them to add to your account.

Comment: OpenSSH includes "ssh-copy-id". It copies the public key to remote machines and adds the key to the authorized_key there.

Comment: @TimHaegele, why are you assuming my second laptop can be accessed from the Internet? It can't be.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add the public key for your second laptop to the server.  Just edit the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file in your home directory and append your second public key.

To get this, on your second laptop, run

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your key (both id_rsa and id_rsa.pub) to you server B with a new name like *serverA_key* and *serverA_key.pub* to connect from serverB with this key you can give ssh the path to your new key

```
ssh -i serverA_key target_server
```

or add this to your .ssh/config on serverB

```
Host target_server
  IdentityFile /path/to/serverA_key
```

Comment: what's a server B?

Comment: serverB means a second system/server

Comment: Where did I mention I have 2 servers? I have 2 laptops.